# SWIFT SpriteKit: How can I use the userData property of an SKnode to decrement the value of a key inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, user-data

Hello everyone (first time asking a question in here!) ,

I am currently trying to use the "userData" property of a SkNode to keep track of a certain value.In the code below , you can see that I created a
node call meteor and use the userData to define a dictionary with the "health" with the value of 3.

```
meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Meteor")
meteor.name = "meteor"
meteor.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
meteor.userData = ["health" : 3]
```

This function create an area blast wherever I touch on the screen

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {
            canonBlastProperties(atPoint: t.location(in: self))
            cannonBlast(delay: 0.001)
        }
}
```

This function that allows the contact between the area blast and the meteor that I have created and is also where I have my issue with.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody, secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "meteor" {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }
        if firstBody.node?.name == "meteor" && secondBody.node?.name == "blast" {
            firstBody.node?.userData?[.value(forKey: "health")] -= 1
//            score += meteorScore
            print("Detected Contact")
        }
}
```

More precisely this line over here is where I have my issue. Technically I'am trying to decrement the specific Meteor "health" by 1 every time its come in contact with the area Blast whenever you touch the screen.

```
firstBody.node?.userData?[.value(forKey: "health")] -= 1
```

Now , SWIFT is giving me this error

`Binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int'`

So, what I understand from this error , correct me if I am wrong, Swift won't allow me to decrement the value of "health" because its of type "Any?".

So what I try is to force cast the Type "Any?" into an "Int".Got another error from that.

I've seem other people with similar issue but the answer they got couldn't really apply to my problem.

I know userData is use to stored data inside specific nodes (I've read swift documentation)

I just want to decrement the VALUE of the key in my dictionary so when it reach 0 the meteor will explode.

Thank you for a swift answer (get it? ;) ) , hope you guys can help me or direct me to the right direction !!

Comment: "Swift won't allow me to decrement the value of "health" because its of type "Any?"."  No.  Simply, that' not how you do it.

Comment: Then how am I suppose to do it? Can you redirect me to a documentation that shows me an example of how to do it or give me an example?

Comment: Set a new dictionary to node's userData property.

Comment: I did and still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, what I did is |        firstBody.node?.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
firstBody.node?.userData? = ["health" : 3]                         firstBody.node?.userData!["health"] -= 1 | (Sorry can't properly indent the code in comment section)

Comment: 1. Why are you using NSMutableDictionary?  2. Why are you ingoring the optional (?)?  Is that how we write code in Swift?  3.  There are two approaches.  If you run a quick search, you will get one of them.  If you want a quick answer, you are never going to get it from me.  So start looking up.

Comment: I actually found out how to make it work. I wasn't looking for a quick answer more like a tip or a more starting point (just start learning swift a week ago). You were talking about "if let" statement or "guard". I actually had a look into these but wasn't sure exactly how optional actually worked. I manage to make it work by doing | if var meteorHealth = firstBody.node?.userData as? [String : Int] {
                meteorHealth["health"]? -= 1
                print(meteorHealth) | but im not exactly sure its the way to go, I'm still looking into it.